# Query does not give output even there is data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this and it give me the correct data.:

```
select * from development.customer_budgets cb
left join development.customer_budget_items cbi on cbi.budget_id = cb.id
left join development.categories c on c.id = cbi.category_id
left join development.tags t on t.id = cbi.tag_id
where cb.customer_id = 1 and t.name = 'Essential';
```

But when i use like this:

```
select * from development.customer_budgets
left join development.customer_budget_items on customer_budget_items.id = customer_budgets.id
left join development.categories on categories.id = customer_budget_items.category_id
left join development.tags on tags.id = customer_budget_items.tag_id 
where customer_budgets.customer_id = 1 and tags.name = 'Essential';
```

no data given even the data is there. What is the difference? am i missing something?

Comment: `left join development.customer_budget_items cbi on cbi.budget_id = cb.id` is not the same as `left join development.customer_budget_items on customer_budget_items.id = customer_budgets.id` -- you searched on `x.budget_id=y.id`, and now you're searching on `x.id=y.id`

Comment: Just stick with the first version of readability.  Side note: `t.name = 'Essential'` might belong in the `ON` clause of one of the joins, rather in the `WHERE` clause.  As you wrote it, your query is probably doing an inner join somewhere instead of an intended left join.

Comment: @richyen ohhh i see, i use a wrong id to join thats why i did not get the results. Thank you so much!